# Checking that a line in an input file has only one int in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read an input file of the format:

```
1  
4  
56  
12
```

With each integer being in a single line.

The objective is to determine that each line is an `int` and that it contains only one `int`. This is my code snippet:

```
std::fstream file(filename, std::ios_base::in);
int num=0;
char c;

file.open(filename);
    while(std::getline(file, line)){
        std::istringstream s(line);
        if(!(s >> num)){
            //error not a number
            file.close();
            std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }else if(s >> c){
            //error there was more than one object in a line
            file.close();
            std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

And the error that I get is this:

```
a5.cpp:28:22: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::basic_istringstream<char,
      std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >'
                std::istringstream s(line);
                                   ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:120:33: note: 
      template is declared here
    class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY basic_istringstream;
```

Comment: Have you included the header `sstream`?

Comment: If you are going to terminate the program if an input fails, you might as well open the stream with exceptions and let it die automatically.

Comment: Oh man you were _so_ close. I thought this question was going to be more `while (!.eof)` nonsense or some terrible `sscanf` implementation. But no ... you just missed out a header! lol ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to include sstream:

```
#include <sstream>
```